# [Edited]VHDL counter won't run

Tags: vhdl, counter

When the num changes, the counter should increase by 1 as the num is in the sensitivity list. But the simulation says no. I wonder what's wrong with my code.
on Quartus 9.0

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY tmp IS
    PORT (
        num : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        counter : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        clr : IN STD_LOGIC
    );
END tmp;

ARCHITECTURE ar OF tmp IS
    SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    PROCESS(num, clr)
    BEGIN
        IF clr'EVENT AND clr = '1' THEN
            c <= "0000";
        END IF;
        c <= c + 1;
    END PROCESS;
    counter <= c;
END;
```

[image: simulation]

Comment: Are you just working in simulation, or do you expect to put this design into a real hardware device? For a start, you need to initialise `c`, but for real hardware, there are other problems with this code!

Comment: Simulation, i just want to test if the process can run, the value of c is nonsense for now :P

Comment: Did you initialise `c`? `SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0') ?`;

Comment: won't help. im using Quartus 9.0, is this too old?

Comment: This question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Quit making scary_jeff shotgun. `C` will potentially change on every event on `num`, providing `C` is initialized to a value representing an unsigned numerical value. Show us what it does do and explain why that isn't right.

Comment: updated, added a picture about simulation.

Comment: What behaviour do you get if you remove the sensitivity list and insert wait on num, clr; as the last statement in the process?

Answer (score 0):

if you use directly counter instead of C , it might help you.
try this

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY tmp IS
    PORT (
        num : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        counter : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        clr : IN STD_LOGIC
    );
END tmp;

ARCHITECTURE ar OF tmp IS

BEGIN
    PROCESS(num, clr)
    BEGIN
        IF clr'EVENT AND clr = '1' THEN
            counter <= "0000";
        END IF;
        counter <= counter + 1;
    END PROCESS;
END;
```

codes out of asynchronous body will run together , so counter will stay same as before

Comment: Quartus II 9.0 says counter must be a buffer, as it was read in the process. And the point is after I changed it to buffer, problem remains. Picture is the same as in the topic.

Comment: No , problem is here , c must be a buffer because it's a counter. The variable which you are using as counter must be buffer

Comment: Sorry I'm quite confused, I mean in your code 'counter' should be a buffer. And the problem remains.